# detect recipient form a multiple recipients in PHP mail() function

Tags: php

i've some problem with a php mail() function,
i've 6000 mail address for mailing list. I want detect a single recipient address foreach email sent, I want to create a link for unsubscrive

for example:

```
<a href="delete.php?email=sample@test.com>unsubscribe</a>"
```

php code:

```
$dests = array("a@mail.com", "b@mail.com", ...); //over 6000 items dinamically sets
$subj = "something";
$body = "something"
. '<a href="delete.php?email=EMAIL_OF_RECIPIENT>unsubscribe</a>"';
$headers = "something";
mail($dests, $subj, $body, $headers);
```

an idea is:

```
foreach($dests as $dest){
$subj = "something";
$body = "something"
. '<a href="delete.php?email=dest>unsubscrive</a>"';
$headers = "something";
mail($dest, $subj, $body, $headers);
}
```

but for more than 100 recipients is a bud idea.

Some solution? thanks in advance.

Comment: Sidenote: Change `foreach(dests as dest){` to `foreach($dests as $dest){` you left out the `$` signs; just so you know how variables work.

Comment: To the first commenter which seems impossible to reply to; have you ever thought that that word might mean "unsubscribe" in the person's native language?

Comment: @Fred-ii- ... what would be hard but ok in this case, isn't it? The OP has no plan about `internet mail` but wants to send 6000 of them. And instead of thinking (like a programmer out of my generation): "Hey looks like I need to dig into `internet mail`. What is it? how does it work?,, ... instead of that he asks a question on SO... Sorry this is not my understand of a programmer or engineer

Comment: @hek2mgl [This user's](http://stackoverflow.com/users/790454/790454) is not taking into consideration that "unsubscrive" could very well be the way it's written in the OP's native language. Then again, it could be a typo, however words as such differ from language to language. (Just saying). I have been criticized before on a similar issue which was a Dutch word.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Looks like I don't got the language problem at all :) I'm from Germany and my English is far from perfect.. I just fell into my 5 minutes of "Hey guys, you are programmers! Behave like that!" ...

Comment: @hek2mgl I know bits and pieces of many languages (6-8) including German ;-) but not all, because there are many including dialects of. I no longer "jump the gun" as it were, when it comes to words like this. guten tag ;-) My Dutch dictionary is growing larger too.

Comment: sorry for my bad english :) "unsubscribe". edited.

Comment: **Key-(Freakin)-Riced**

Answer (score 0):

Why is it a bad idea?  Performance I assume.  Sending 6000 emails is going to take a while (I hope this is in some kind of background/async action).  You might even want to deliberately stagger it to be nicer to your mail server/ISP.  Or set a longer max execution time for this script than others.

One small improvement would be to move as much as possible out of the loop.  Doing that (and cleaning up your code to work - $ on the variables, full URL for the unsubscribe link and swapping the single and double quotes so that the inline variable is interpreted):

```
$subj = "something";
$body = "something";
$headers = "something";
foreach($dests as $dest){    
  mail($dest, $subj, $body . "<a href='http://example.com/delete.php?email=$dest'>unsubscrive</a>", $headers);
}
```

Comment: All emails will be sent correctly? no server error or crash for over 6000 recipients?

Comment: That depends on your timeouts and architechiture.  You might want to consider "queing" addresses in a database and then marking as sent (to allow better recovery from crashes while sending) or deliberately staging the sending of the mails over time (e.g. queue them all in a database then have a scheduled job which sends the next X queued mails every Y minutes).  It will take longer to complete (i.e. until all have been sent) but will be more robust.  Mass-mailing programs are not usually instantaneous

Comment: every http request dont' send more than 50/60 emails. There is a limit server